# Интерфейс C# с использованием кода Python в качестве скрипта

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x

Мне нужна помощь. Я хочу создать графический интерфейс-оболочку на C# для программы, написанной на Python (использование Python в качестве скрипта для C#).

Есть ли какие-нибудь теории или книги об этом? Благодарю!

Comment: А зачем такие хитрости? У питона свои GUI библиотеки в общем-то есть.

Comment: И программу на шарпе целиком можно нарисать, чтобы не извращаться.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/). Это интерпретатор Python в среде .NET. Его сравнительно легко использвать из C#. Последняя доступная версия 3.4 (текущая версия обычного Питона 3.10). Но это лучше чем ничего.